# Certain Apps crashes in Catalina

Tags: catalina, crash

I last few days I noticed that some Apps are crashing and/or reporting unexpected quit. **Photo Booth** does this after few seconds (crashes) and **RStudio** reports unexpected quit and gives a crash report after normal Quit (Cmd+Q).

I am under the latest **macOS Catalina**, and I am using the latest **RStudio** 1.2.5033. (I cannot see details of **Photo Booth** as it crashes too quickly.)

Is anyone experiencing the same? Any fixes?

Answer (score 1):

Without considerably more information, it's impossible to pinpoint the cause.

However, PhotoBooth is an Apple-supplied app that comes with the OS, so it should not crash under normal conditions. The likelihood is that you've got something installed which is causing both these apps to crash.

I would recommend using [EtreCheck](https://www.etrecheck.com), which is an excellent app that gives you a report of the 'state' of your system. It highlights third-party additions that are potential sources of problems, particularly if they are old and no longer compatible with a new OS.

You can upload the contents of the report here (or somewhere list [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com)) if you need more help.

Comment: Unfortunately, EtreCheck does not give much:

Diagnostics Information (past 7-30 days):
    2020-04-02 13:27:18 RStudio.app - Crash (16 times)
        Executable: /Applications/RStudio.app
        Details:
            abort() called

    2020-04-02 10:49:49 Photo Booth.app - Crash (4 times)
        Executable: /System/Applications/Photo Booth.app
        Details:
            dyld3 mode
            abort() called

Comment: @striatum Click on the "Review" button on "Minor Issues", and you should get a detailed list of stuff.

Comment: This is it! Not much...